# sistema é computacionalmente singular: condição recíproca número

Tags: r

Estou tratando de séries temporais no R.
Meus Dados são Homocedásticos, não possuem autocorrelação, não tem raiz unitária no lag=0, tendencia ou sazonalidade.

Ainda sim esbarro no problema deste erro especifico:

```
    VAR_S <- summary(VAR(Base_Dados,p = 1, type = "both"))
```

> Error in solve.default(Sigma) :
>
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number =
>           5.67068e-37
>
> ```
> VAR<- (VAR(Base_Dados, p = 1, type = "both" ) )
> ```

A principio achei que fosse colinearidade, porém a correlação dos dados não supera 0,25.

Comment: Você pode estar trabalhando com algo realmente independente, logo o vetor autorregressivo tende a um vetor nulo.

Comment: Acho que entendi, sera possível ver isso com determinantes da matriz talvez?

Answer (score 1):

A matriz não pode ser inversível o determinante da matriz é zero ou aproximadamente zero.
Lidei com isso de duas maneiras distinta, mudeis os dados para um modelo parecido que funcionou más n demonstrou o resultado desejado para análise.
quanto ao modelo anterior a forma encontrada de resolução, foi re avaliar a escala das variáveis elas deixaram de estar na mesma escalada unitária mas passaram a ter aproximadamente a mesma quantidade de número inteiros por observação.

Foi um trabalho intuitivo, logo não tenho formulas para demonstrar.